# Dual Boot Ubuntu 2020 without creating partition. Cannot open Windows now

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, windows-10, boot-repair

I had dual booted Ubuntu 2020 from Windows 10. However, I had forgotten to allocate separate partition from Windows.
When I restart, I can see Windows in the grub but Windows in not opening. I tried Windows troubleshooting, also tried to restore the last restore point- it showed that restoration was successful but still I was unable to open Windows.
I have access to Ubuntu and I can access the files in Windows but not able to open Windows OS.

Comment: You use Windows tools for Windows & Linux tools for Linux. Or only use Windows to shrink the NTFS partition and use gparted or installer to create Linux partitions in unallocated space. Grub only boots working Windows and Windows fast start up must be off and UEFI Secure boot off for grub to boot Windows. If UEFI install, can you directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, not grub?

Comment: As above but also if you actually din't start with unallocated space for Ubuntu then very likely you overwrote the Windows partition, therefore your Windows is gone.

Comment: @oldfred Hello, I had tried the UEFI and it tries to troubleshoot but it cannot do anything :/

Comment: @ChanganAuto If Windows was gone, I should not have been able to access the Windows files though. Right?

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (details in 2nd option in Boot-Repair link) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred
Hello, I am pasting the pastebin link here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/n3yjksmnVM/
Thank you for your help till now.

Comment: You show 3 larger NTFS partitions, a Windows UEFI boot loader in UEFI, but then no Windows boot files in ESP. As if /EFI/Microsoft folder was deleted. That cannot be fixed from Linux, you need your Windows repair/recovery flash drive and run a full set of repairs to restore Windows boot files. I believe Windows 10 repairs would be similar to this which was Windows 8. https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader

Comment: But I am not able to enter the Windows system in itself. So I am unsure of how to do that.